# UWP and .NET Core versioning?

Tags: uwp, .net-core, versioning

I’m looking for a way to find out what version of .NET Core and .Net Standard is used by my UWP application (I’m using it o Raspberry Pi). In project properties (in VS 2017) I can see target platform 15063 and in nugget I have Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 5.3.1 but there is no .NET Core explicitly there like in .NET Core library. There are dependencies on UniversalWindowsPlatform but versioning is confusing:

Microsoft.NETCore (>= 5.0.2)
Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR (>= 1.0.3)

I can see .NET core version that is used when I’m deploying for the first time:

“Framework: Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1/ARM, app package version 1.1.25129.1 is not currently installed.”

But I don’t know how to check it in other way. Can somebody explain how to check this this and from what factor it depends of what .NET Core version is used in UWP app – is target platform matter?

And additionally what is the .NET Core (>= 5.0.2) – as far as I know .NET Core was In 1.0, 1.1 and future is 2.0. What is this 5.0.2?

Answer (score 1):

Do not mixup .NET Core and UWP. Both use the same CLR named CoreCLR which was generated for the Silverlight Project. The UWP SDK is in version 5.x (CoreCLR based for debugging / .NET Native for released products) and the cross platform .NET Core SDK is in version 1.0.0. To make it worse, the CoreCLR is independently versioned: 1.0.3 / 1.0.4.

And to make it even worse .NET Core (generally, including the SDK) has another version 1.1. Same is true for the UWP which is aligned with the Windows platform (afaik).

Horrible right. They messed up the naming of it. And the communication.