# Can UAP applications consume .net8 libraries?

Tags: uwp

I have a large library of code targeting .net8. I'm now building UAP applications that need to consume these libraries but I get this warning when I attempt to build an executable:

> Warning   NU1701  Package 'GammaFour.Data.Client 4.2.1' was restored
> using 'net8.0-windows10.0.22000, .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1,
> .NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0, .NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.8, net8.0-windows10.0.22000,
> .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework
> 'UAP,Version=v10.0.22000'. This package may not be fully compatible
> with your project.    ThetaRex.OpenBook.Desktop
> (Package) C:\Users\Shepard\source\repos\Theta-Rex\openbook-desktop\ThetaRex.OpenBook.Desktop
> (Package)\ThetaRex.OpenBook.Desktop (Package).wapproj 1

I've tried retargeting to .net6 and .net7 with the same results. Oddly, it's only my libraries that are flagged. I'm pulling in several other libraries like Microsoft.Extensions.Logging that don't generate the same warning. I can't find any documentation to suggest what they have that I don't have.

Comment: The library you're referring to only seems to [target .NET 8](https://github.com/DonaldAirey/GammaFour.Data.Client/blob/main/GammaFour.Data.Client/GammaFour.Data.Client.csproj#L24C48-L24C48)

Comment: Great. How do I get it to target UAP?

Comment: Fork the project, open the csproj file, add `;uap10.0.10586.0` inside `<TargetFrameworks></TargetFrameworks>`, open a pull-request, and wait for a new release

Comment: Or fork the project, do the same as above, and release a nuget package yourself

Answer (score 0):

> Can UAP applications consume .net8 libraries?

No. And not `.net6` or `.net7` libraries either.

A library that is meant to be consumed from both a UWP app and a .NET app is supposed to target [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077).

The `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` package targets .NET Standard 2.0 (and also `.net6` and `.net462`) for example.

[UWP and recent versions of .Net (6, 8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77493086/uwp-and-recent-versions-of-net-6-8/77493885#77493885)